# Google Spreadsheets .NET API - 409 Conflict

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

This question is in regards to the .NET API for google spreadsheets.  I just started having this problems when I used the =now() function in one of my cells in the spreadsheet.

I am trying to change the contents of the cell to be empty but currently has the function
"=now()" whenever I do this I get the following exception:

Unhandled Exception: Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException:
Execution of request failed:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/tCwx4BBDlqy68FkCwQY06Sw/o...
---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
(409) Conflict.

My code is:

```
curCell.Cell.InputValue = "";
AtomEntry updatedCell = curCell.Update();
```

Im just trying to clear the contents of the cell.  If my cell has a
regular string in it, such as "time" it will clear out the contents
without any problems.  So this error seems to be related to trying to
change contents of cell when =now() is currently the value.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide which API version this is about... current version is AFAIK V 3.0 - according to [this](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#UpdatingCells) in the earlier version it was ok to use `POST`for such an operation BUT this is no longer recommended, instead `PUT`should be used.

IF you are not sure which version you are using you can find out what's going over the wire by using Fiddler and/or Wireshark...

Comment: I am trying, but I cant find the download link.  The version I have is what is listed here: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list
Google_Data_API_Setup_1.9.0.0.msi

Comment: @Ron that means Google didn't update the .NET API to the newest Spreadsheet API V3 :-( which means you might need to implement the API V 3 yourself to be fully compatible with the current server-side of Google Spreadsheet :-(

Comment: There is some confusion here between versions of the .NET client library and the Spreadsheets API. The library supports many different APIs and as such it has its own version number. The client library is currently at version 2.0.1 and fully implements v3 of the Spreadsheets API.